# Angular 5 with NGRX - what to use for loading data depending on route

Tags: angular, angular-routing, ngrx

It's still not clear to me on what technique to use to load missing (in a Store) data when user navigates to a particular route. [Here](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/example-app/app/books/guards/book-exists.ts) guys use Guards, and @vsavkin uses other technique in his [State sample](https://github.com/vsavkin/state_management_ngrx4/blob/master/clientapp/src/app/model.ts). So, are there any guidelines on how to do this?

**UPDATE**: There's also Resolve for the route! Which I consider the 3rd option.

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of preference, and as far as I'm aware there are no guidelines for anything like this yet.

I personally prefer and tend to use the guards approach. Effects can be nice in certain circumstances but I find that they become difficult to manage as your application (and your API) grow. I like to use them in more of an AOP fashion, where side effects simply occur but are not a part of the primary procedure, rather than in a declarative way where your application cannot continue without the execution of the effect. I believe that services are perfectly well-suited for API calls.

You could also make the argument that guards are a more orthodox pattern since they are a core part of the Angular router, whereas ngrx is a library.